# Hibernate 5.2.10: Unable to perform unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, java-9

## Edit 5: Solved

The main problem was that I've used JDK 9, where the JAXB APIs are no longer on on the default class path. Here is [link where I've found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j).

---

I used hibernate version 4.3.6 from example tutorial and everything've worked good, but when I update version to 5.2.10 I have problem (I know that code responsible for getSessionFactory is different so I changed it).

My first function:

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

And my function in 5.2.10 version:

```
private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){

    StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

    MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

    Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

    sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    return sessionFactory;

}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to
>   perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE
>   hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null

and hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM


"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.Item"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Where is the problem? I've tried everything.

## Edit: pom.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Edit 2

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
    try {
        StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry =
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        Metadata metaData =
                new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
    } catch (Throwable th) {

        System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);

    }
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    return sessionFactory;

}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name="emp_address")
    private String empAddress;

    @Column(name="emp_mobile_nos")
    private String empMobileNos;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }

    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

    public String getEmpMobileNos() {
        return empMobileNos;
    }

    public void setEmpMobileNos(String empMobileNos) {
        this.empMobileNos = empMobileNos;
    }

}
```

Testing class.

```
  public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmpName("Deepak Kumar");
        emp.setEmpMobileNos("000000");
        emp.setEmpAddress("Delhi - India");
        session.save(emp);
        tr.commit();
        System.out.println("Successfully inserted");
        sessFact.close();
    }

}
```

## Edit 3

```
lis 17, 2017 11:54:50 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
lis 17, 2017 11:54:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
lis 17, 2017 11:54:50 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Enitial SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pl.lostandfound.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:31)
    at pl.lostandfound.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at pl.lostandfound.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:241)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:477)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:122)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:594)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:239)
    ... 9 more
```

## Edit 4

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Enitial SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JPA; so please remove the tag.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no I'm using hibernate 5.

Comment: @senham, right! Have just tried to reproduce the problem using a minimal example: cannot reproduce. Could you please post the content of the `pom.xml`?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov Sure, I've just edited my post.

Comment: @senham, good: still cannot reproduce. Let's continue. Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem? For example, a short, but complete Java program with the main method and the one entity.

Comment: @SergeyBrunov It is just example that I've found, but I try 3 different examples from tutorials one with hibernate 4 and everything was ok, then I try the same example project with hibernate 5 and I've seen this exception and now I've tried this example but it's the same.

Comment: @senham, still cannot reproduce the problem using the provided complete example: the employee gets inserted correctly. Also, could you please post the Hibernate log messages?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov Edit3: Is this what you mind?

Comment: I do not think the two questions are relate, because here parsing has not even started due to missing class error. Check my answer below.

Comment: Related question: [java - Connection with MySQL database. Xml error Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862138).

Comment: @senham, good. At least it gives more details. What JRE do you use (`java -version`) to run the application?

Comment: @senham, as a last resort, I would like to propose you to post the minimal and complete example, you are using, somehow: GitHub, zip archive, etc.

Comment: @senham, it seems my guess about the JRE version has helped.

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly first fix the ClassNotFound Exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory). This indicated that a class that needed to be loaded is not present...

Maybe adding the following dependency would fix your problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Most recent version taken from here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl

If the ClassNotFound exception is still there...I would look more closely what version of JAXB hibernate is using. A very nice way to analyze your dependencies are the following two commands:

```
mvn clean dependency:analyze
```

and

```
mvn clean dependency:tree
```

**For Edit4:** check following answers:

[ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] in project root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879613/configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg-xml-resource-hibernate-cfg-xml-in)

[Location of hibernate.cfg.xml in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project)

Comment: Still not working, I've even created new project but it's the same.

Comment: Look at the updated answer, please. Add jaxb-core as dependency also.

Comment: When I've added log4j dependency and hibernate jpa dependency I have somehthing like this:edit4.

Comment: ok, I try add jaxb-core

Comment: With jabxb-core exception looks the same as in edit4.

Comment: Well nice, then it fixed the problem with the missing class. Now your hibernate.cfg.xml cannot be found...check links in answer, please.

Comment: I give up... thank you so much for help but I really can't find the problem, when I have hibernate 4.3.6 everything is ok, when I change it to 5.2.x I have exceptions...

Comment: I think that the problem is in intellij configuration, because even if I use example project from github I have still the same problem with class.