# How to resolve error "Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml " .

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Getting error 
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml.

hibernate.cfg.xml file is root src folder.

hibernate.cfg.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property 
 name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property 
 name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BOOKSTORE</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">abcd@1</property>
    <property 
    name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.model.Book" />  
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: The `INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found` is a separate log message and not the error. Could you paste the stack trace from the logs. My suspicion is that it's because you're using Java 9 (or newer) and you're running into this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358903/hibernate-5-2-10-unable-to-perform-unmarshalling

Comment: I am not using maven.

Comment: But if you are using Java 9 or newer, that does explain your problem, and you just need to add the shown dependencies on whatever build system you are using.